# Why can't I manually do a horizontal scroll?

Tags: uiscrollview

Scenario:

I have four (4) colored UIViews within a horizonal Stack View which is within a UIScrollView:

[image]

Here's the UIScrollView properties: 
[image]

I'm *able to programically scroll* without problem as demoed within the viewDidLayoutSubviews:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 1500, height: scrollView.frame.size.height)

        let myRect = CGRect(x: 930, y: 0, width: 300, height: 400)
        scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(myRect, animated: true)

        return
    }

}
```

But the scroll refuses to move out of its initial position (i.e., it *slides back to its original position* without advancing beyond the next colored UIView):

[image]

Why?  Solution?

**Note:** The UIScrollViewDelegate is logging continual scrolling... but only to/from this hidden barrier.

Answer (score 0):

After some some research, I found that I was missing one (1) constraint for my autolayout UI.

[image]